# Changing couchdb database directory leads to 502 error

Tags: couchdb

I am currently running a couchdb server on AWS M5ad.xlarge instance.

I have mounted the 150 gb drive separately.

I am trying to point the couchdb data directory to the mounted drive.

However, when I do so, I get a 502 error when I try to access port 5984.

Kindly let me know how to solve this

I have mounted the drive in /var/mydata

I have added the following in my couchdb local.ini file

```
[couchdb]
database_dir = /var/mydata
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding a symlink to the data folder in /opt/couchdb/